# ASP.NET When redirecting from a error also get the path

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a website right now and when people have 404 it redirects them using this code.

```
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/errors/404.aspx?path="/>
</customErrors>
```

How can I make it so when it is redirecting them it also puts the path its redirecting them from?

So if they were on mysite.com/shfsd.aspx it would redirect as `/errors/404.aspx?path=shfsd.aspx`

Comment: If you remove the `?path=`, it will redirect to `/errors/404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/Some/Path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to capture the URL referrer in a query string like this.

However, you could easily add code to your `404.aspx.cs` code-behind and do what you like with it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Url != null)
        {
            var url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            //Do something like write to log file etc.
            //log.Write(url);
        }
        else
        {
            //Handle error from client who directly entered URL..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try out!

Comment: @LoganRisen no problem, please do not forget to mark the question answered if this helps you out. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                {
                    var urlReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
                Label1.Text = urlReferrer;
                }
                else
                {
                
            }` Is what I did and nothing is happening labels not changing...

Comment: @LoganRisen I have modified the code above, please try `Url` instead of `UrlReferrer`.

Comment: now thats getting the current request, not the last request.

Comment: Can you add this `<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">` and try it again.